# Hibernate: multiple @ManyToMany relations in a single table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a project where Hibernate is used to manage entities. Multiple @ManyToMany relations can exists between two tables. So basically i have code like this:

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "movies_screenplay_authors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false, updatable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", nullable = false, updatable = false))
private Set<Staff> screenplayAuthors = Sets.newHashSet();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "movies_story_authors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false, updatable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", nullable = false, updatable = false))
private Set<Staff> storyAuthors = Sets.newHashSet();
```

Now, I would like to store those relations inside a single table, with some additional column describing relation type. So basically, I would like to have something like this (pseudo-code used):

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "movies_staff",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false, updatable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", nullable = false, updatable = false),
        joinCriteria = @JoinCriteria(columnName = "staff_type", value = StaffType.SCREENPLAY_AUTHOR, enumType = EnumType.STRING))
private Set<Staff> screenplayAuthors = Sets.newHashSet();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "movies_staff",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false, updatable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staff_id", nullable = false, updatable = false),
        joinCriteria = @JoinCriteria(columnName = "staff_type", value = StaffType.STORY_AUTHOR, enumType = EnumType.STRING))
private Set<Staff> storyAuthors = Sets.newHashSet();
```

Is this even possible, in Hibernate, or anywhere in Java world?

Comment: You mean a single (shared) join table, like in this example http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_shared_join  That is outside the scope of JPA, but that JPA provider (DataNucleus) does it, no idea about Hibernate

Comment: Thanks. It's a valueable a link.

Comment: Are those relations overlapping? If not, a somewhat more awkward yet portable solution would be to use `@ElementCollection` with a `Map<Staff, Role>` where role is an enum of possible relation roles (`ScreenplayAuthor`, `StoryAuthor` etc.)

Comment: Yes, relations quite ofter overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can add after each @JoinTable annotation something like this:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
```

And its all.